# PHP. Как изменить значения массива через форму на сайте?

Tags: php, массивы

мне необходимо изменить значение массива через форму на сайте.

Есть два файла, а именно index.php и array.php

В файле array.php находится массив:

```
$array = [
  'key1' => 'Значение 1',
  'key2' => 'Значение 2'
];
```

В файле index.php циклом вывожу значения, выглядит приблизительно так:

```
foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
    echo "<input name=\"save_config[$key]\" type=\"text\" value=\"$value\">";
}
```

Цикл выводит все значения массива и добавляет к name ключ массива и соответственно к value значение.

Но проблема следующая, если зайти на страницу index.php всё отображается как следует, поля input заполнены данными из массива, если изменить значения в input и нажать "save" всё работает корректно, но если не нажать "save", а просто обновить страницу, то функция fwrite сотрет всё в файле array.php так как "ничего не передано".

Весь код index.php:

```
<?
require_once __DIR__ . '/array.php';
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        echo "<input name=\"save_config[$key]\" type=\"text\" value=\"$value\">";
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
<?
$save_config = $_POST['save_config'];
$handler = fopen('array.php', "w+");

fwrite($handler, "<?PHP \n\n\$config = [\n");
foreach ($save_config as $name => $value) {
    fwrite($handler, "   '{$name}'    => '{$value}',\n");
}
fwrite($handler, "];");
fclose($handler);
```

Какой существует способ не удалять данные в файле array.php при перезагрузке страницы? В голову приходит только if проверка, но не представляю какую именно проверку можно вставить в if.

Долгое время искал примеры, но не нашел ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Первый способ**: для button задать свойство name.

```
<button type="submit" name="save">save</button>
```

Проверять, что форма была отправлена:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    // do something
}
```

**Второй способ**: задать скрытое поле для формы и проверять, что форма была отправлена

```
<input type="hidden" hidden name="save_form" value="1"/>

if (1 == intval($_POST['save_form'])){
    // do something
}
```

**Третий способ**: проверять, не пустой ли массив пришёл

```
if (!empty($save_config)){
    // do something
}
```